# sed - match NOT beginning of line

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I am trying to write a command that replaces text NOT at the beginning of the line:

```
echo -e 'a b b\nb b c' | sed 's%^b%x%g'
```

Output:

```
a b b
x b c
```

Desired output:

```
a x x
b x c
```

I'm writing a script that parses a 400 MB file, and I've been banging my head on this one for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for multiple chars together:

```
sed 's/^b/\
/; s/b/x/g; s/^\n/b/'
```

Some sed's accept `\n` in the replacement part so in that case

```
sed 's/^b/\n/; s/b/x/g; s/^\n/b/'
```

ought to work too

Comment: Nice (sneaky) use of a newline in the pattern space. :-)

Comment: Thanks :) Nice that you noticed this use of newline ;)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
echo -e 'a b b\nb b c' | sed 's%\(.\)b%\1x%g'
```

Comment: Will not replace all occurrences if there are multiple `b` together.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize that was a requirement.

Comment: It may not be, I'm not the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [Scrutinizer's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752242/1256452), here's a more generalized method of protecting part of a line.  The trick is that we take the (single line) pattern space and insert a newline after the "part to protect".  Then, we make changes only to "that which comes after a newline".  Finally, we remove the protective newline.

This version changes all `b`s except for any (one-or-more) "start of line" `b`s, so, e.g., "b b c" becomes "b x c" but "bbc bbc" becomes "bbc bxc" rather than "bxc bxc".

```
sed -e 's/^b*/&\
/
s/\n\(.*\)b/\1x/g
s/\n//'
```

(The same method can be used to protect text towards the end of a line, although it's significantly more difficult.)

(Note: this is not as efficient, as sed now has to change every line, once to add the protector and then again to remove it.  If you really just wanted to protect multiple leading `b`s you could turn them all into newlines, and then turn them back.  This is more meant to allow protecting, e.g., the first "word" on every line.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Perl available on your system? In that case, this would work as a direct replacement of the sed command:

```
perl -pe '($c,$_)=/(.)(.*)/s;s/b/x/g;$_=$c.$_'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^b/s/b/x/2g;/^b/!s/b/x/g' file
```

or

```
sed -r ':a;s/^(..*)b/\1x/;ta' file
```